# GraphHopper does not obey bicycle=no

Tags: routes, graphhopper

I have installed a local copy of GraphHopper yesterday, but its result is not consistent with the demo server, specifically it routes through sections marked with bicycle=no:

My server (wrong):
http://tile.miklcct.csproject.org:8989/?point=22.318106%2C114.162675&point=22.317262%2C114.156554&vehicle=bike&locale=en-GB&elevation=true&layer=MapQuest

Demo server (right):
https://graphhopper.com/maps/?point=22.318106%2C114.162675&point=22.317262%2C114.156554&vehicle=bike&locale=en-GB&elevation=true&layer=MapQuest

config.properties

```
##### Vehicles #####
#
# Possible options: car,foot,bike,bike2,mtb,racingbike,motorcycle (comma separated)
# bike2 takes elevation data into account (like up-hill is slower than down-hill)
# and requires enabling graph.elevation.provider below
graph.flagEncoders=bike

# Enable turn restrictions for car or motorcycle. 
# Currently you need to additionally set prepare.chWeighting=no before using this (see below and #270)
# graph.flagEncoders=car|turnCosts=true


##### Elevation #####
#
# To populate your graph with elevation data use SRTM, default is noop
graph.elevation.provider=srtm
#
# default location for cache is /tmp/srtm
# graph.elevation.cachedir=./srtmprovider/
#
# If you have a slow disk or plenty of RAM change the default MMAP to:
graph.elevation.dataaccess=RAM_STORE



##### Storage #####
#
# configure the memory access, use RAM_STORE for well equipped servers, 
# MMAP_STORE_SYNC could be used otherwise but will be a lot slower
graph.dataaccess=RAM_STORE

# if you want to reduce storage size and you don't need instructions for the resulting path use:
# osmreader.instructions=false

#### Speed-up Mode vs. Flexibility Mode ####
#
# By default the speed-up mode with the 'fastest' weighting is used. Internally a graph preparation via
# contraction hierarchies is done to speed routing up. This requires more RAM/disc space for holding the
# graph but less for every request. Also only the first vehicle of the flagEncoders list will be prepared.
# prepare.chWeighting=fastest
#
# Disable the speed-up mode (contraction hierarchies, CH) via enabling the flexibility mode:
prepare.chWeighting=no


##### Web #####
# if you want to support jsonp response type you need to add it explicitely here. By default it is disabled for 
# stronger security.
# web.jsonpAllowed=true
```

How can I correctly configure it to obey restrictions? I am using the latest master branch.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it is not a problem of graphhopper. The problem is the data source I was using which came from Hong Kong "metro extract" and I have replaced it with the China map from geofabrik.de . The problem has been fixed.